# Guardar valor de tipo fecha en SQL en servidor en-US

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estoy tratando de guardar un `string` de tipo `date` en un campo de la base de datos, pero al intentar guardar una fecha cuyo día supere el día 12, me devuelve el siguiente error:

> *String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.*

He intentado formatear la fecha con `TryParse` y `TryParseExact` sin éxito.

Estoy intentado guardar este valor en una entidad de EF por reflexión:

Ejemplo:

```
 propertyInfo.SetValue(inputObject, Convert.ToDateTime(propertyVal).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), null);
```

¿Cómo sería la forma correcta de guardar el valor `Date` en una base de datos con configuración `en-US`?

El valor a guardar sería del tipo `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: para evitar problemas de configuración de lenguaje, debes usar un string con formato no ambiguo. En tu caso, puedes probar el formato `yyyyMMdd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al superar el día 12 y te lanza error, es porque en realidad en ese campo le pertenece al `mes`. A continuación un ejemplo para entendernos mejor:

```
string fecha = "10/22/2016"; // 22 Octubre 2016
Console.WriteLine("Fecha ingresada: "+fecha);
DateTime fechaFormateada = DateTime.ParseExact(fecha, "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
Console.WriteLine("Fecha con formato: "+fechaFormateada); // 2016-10-22 12:00:00 AM
Console.WriteLine("Fecha con formato corto: "+fechaFormateada.ToShortDateString()); // 2016-10-22
Console.WriteLine("Dia: " + fechaFormateada.Day); //22
Console.WriteLine("Mes: " + fechaFormateada.Month); //10
Console.WriteLine("Anio: " + fechaFormateada.Year);//2016       
Console.ReadLine();
```

Generando como resultado:

```
Fecha ingresada: 10/22/2016
Fecha con formato: 10/22/2016 12:00:00 AM
Fecha con formato corto: 10/22/2016
Dia: 22
Mes: 10
Anio: 2016
```

En la tercera linea donde se define el formato como **"MM/dd/yyyy"** es por el formato que utilizas. Para mayor informacion, revisa: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

## ¿como seria la forma correcta de guardar el valor Date en una base de datos con setting en-US?

Suponiendo que el campo en la base de datos es de tipo `DateTime` o `Date`, el formato de fecha que no te dará problemas para representar una fecha como cadena en una sentencia Insert/Update, con SQL Server instalado y configurado en diferentes idiomas, es **YYYYMMDD** para solo fecha y **YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS** para fecha/hora. Si, sin guiones y con dos puntos; **sé que es extraño** si tienes background de otra base de datos, pero así es SQL Server (y no voy a defenderlo).

Con esto en mente, podrías modificar tu código a esto:

```
propertyInfo.SetValue(inputObject,  Convert.ToDateTime(propertyVal).ToString("yyyyMMdd"), null);
```

Y en teoría debiera funcionar

Dicho esto...

## Evita utilizar representaciones textuales para fechas, números, etc.

Las interfaces de acceso a datos de la mayoría de los lenguajes modernos, tiene la capacidad de realizar bien la tarea de enviar y recuperar información correctamente a prácticamente cualquier motor de base de datos, si tu representas los datos en formatos nativos del lenguaje. Los autores de los *drivers* de los diferentes motores se han encargado de estos pequeños grandes detalles (que si el separador decimal es un punto, o una coma, que si la fecha se representa de una forma o de otra). De hecho, muchos clientes de base de datos aceptarán los datos binarios, con lo que también se optimiza el tiempo de proceso y viaje por la red.

Si puedes, envía las fechas como fechas, los números como números, etc. y olvídate para siempre de estos problemas.

Comment: Perfecto, probare la inserción con el formato de fecha que comentas. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Ampliando la respuesta de @jachguate, el formato "yyyyMMdd" se denomina "formato de cadena sin separar" (UnseparatedStringFormat), este formato es multilingüe e independiente del DATEFORMAT establecido, por lo que no importa tu configuración guardará correctamente en la base de datos.

Cito:

> Los formatos del literal de cadena afectan a la presentación de datos en aplicaciones de los usuarios, pero no al formato subyacente de almacenamiento de enteros en SQL Server. Sin embargo, SQL Server podría interpretar un valor de fecha en un formato del literal de cadena, proporcionado por una aplicación o usuario para el almacenamiento o a una función de fecha, como fechas diferentes. La interpretación depende de la combinación de formato del literal de cadena, del tipo de datos y de la configuración en tiempo de ejecución de SET DATEFORMAT, SET LANGUAGE y de la opción de idioma predeterminada.

Más información: [Usar datos de fecha y hora (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms180878.aspx#UnseparatedStringFormat)